# Change the style of element B during the hover event to A

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, hover

How do you change the style of element B when you move the mouse over element A if element A is in the DOM below element B?

In example:

```
<div id="B">Text</div>
<button id="A">Btn</button>
```

Below not working:

```
#A:hover + #B {color: red;}
#A:hover ~ #B {color: red;}
#A:hover #B {color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ok, this answer is now not right as the question has been modified. (Mistake from the author).

You have to invert your ids to have this : `#B:hover + #A {color: red;}`

Because its **"When hovering #B target the next element #A and add color: red;"**

```css
#B:hover + #A {color: red;}
```

```html
<div id="B">Text</div>
<button id="A">Btn</button>
```

Comment: My bad! I want to change style B element when hover on A element >_<

Comment: So I regret to inform you that it's not possible to target previous element with css. You will need the help of JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, thx for the answer.